# Different result for integral of $(x+1)^2$ depending on technique used

Tags: calculus, substitution

So I might be completely wrong, and I surely am, but I tried solving a very simple looking integral, but depending on what I do to solve it, I get different results. Here's what I did for the first try:
$$
\int(x+1)^2dx\\
t=x+1,\ dx=dt\\
\int t^2dt=\frac{t^3}{3}+C=\frac{(x+1)^3}{3}+C
$$
Surely this is correct, but when I do not use substitution and just evaluate the integral in itself, it gives me this:
$$
\int(x+1)^2dx=\int x^2+2x+1\ dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+x^2+x+C=\frac{(x+1)^3-1}{3}+C
$$
So which one is it, or is there just something that allows both solutions to exist?

Comment: The two antiderivatives are the same up to a constant.

Comment: They are the same ... remember the arbitrary constant!

Comment: Yeah I see, any other number, when re-differentiated, will disappear, so they are part of that C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.

The $C$ in your second result equals the $C$ in your first result plus $1/3$.

Also note if you did a *definite* integral i.e. $\int_a^b$  then your first result gives
$$
\left[ \frac{(b+1)^3}{3}+C \right ]-\left[ \frac{(a+1)^3}{3}+C \right ]\\
= \frac{(b+1)^3}{3}-\frac{(a+1)^3}{3}\\
$$
and the second results gives
$$
\left[ \frac{(b+1)^3-1}{3}+C \right ]-\left[ \frac{(a+1)^3-1}{3}+C \right ]\\
= \frac{(b+1)^3}{3}-\frac{(a+1)^3}{3}\\
$$
i.e. the same again.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about the $+C$!  This is why you get this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(x+1)^3}{3}+D=\frac{(x+1)^3-1}{3}+C$$

We have $$D= -\frac13+C$$

The solution differs by a constant (which will vanish if you differentiate it)

Answer (score 2):

Constant when integrated over $t\ne$ Constant when integrated over $x$